# How to retain the scrolled position of a Recyclerview on back press from another activity and i fetch data from firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I use fragments inside this i fetch data from firebase database. i use card view to dispaly data, by clicking each cardview i reach to the new activity but when i press the back button, the recycler view load again and the recyclerview page starts from the top. i want to retain the recyclerview position.please help how to retain the scroll view position.

```
public class StationaryDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView pendingOrder_row;
private DatabaseReference orderDatabase;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter orderRecyclerAdapter;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private String rollnumber , mobilenumber, collegename, hostelname, key;
private ArrayList<String> title2 = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stationarydetail, container, false);
    pendingOrder_row = v.findViewById(R.id.pendingOrder_row);
    pendingOrder_row.setHasFixedSize(true);
    pendingOrder_row.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    orderDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("StationaryConfirmOrder");

        orderDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            key= dataSnapshot.getKey();
            title2.add(key);
            Log.i("key",key);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return v;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<details> optioner =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<details>()
                    .setQuery(orderDatabase, details.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .build();
    orderRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<details, orderViewHolder>(optioner){

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public orderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new orderViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.stat_order_cnfrow, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final orderViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull details model) {
            final String userid = model.getUserid();
            final String price = model.getPrice();
            final String Quantity = model.getQuantity();
            final String Name = model.getName();
            final String key2 = title2.get(position);
            holder.setUserId(key2);

            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userid);
            databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    rollnumber = dataSnapshot.child("rollNumber").getValue().toString();
                    mobilenumber = dataSnapshot.child("mobileNumber").getValue().toString();
                    collegename = dataSnapshot.child("collegeName").getValue().toString();
                    hostelname = dataSnapshot.child("hostelName").getValue().toString();
                    Log.i("user", rollnumber+"/"+ mobilenumber+"/"+collegename+"/"+hostelname);
                    holder.setName(rollnumber);
                    holder.setPrice(hostelname +", "+ collegename);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            holder.orderCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Intent orderDetail = new Intent(getActivity(),stat_con_order.class);
                    orderDetail.putExtra("userid",userid);
                    orderDetail.putExtra("price",price);
                    orderDetail.putExtra("Quantity",Quantity);
                    orderDetail.putExtra("Name",Name);
                    orderDetail.putExtra("orderid",key2);
                    startActivity(orderDetail);


                }
            });




        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return title2.size();
        }
    };
    pendingOrder_row.setAdapter(orderRecyclerAdapter);
    orderRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    pendingOrder_row.smoothScrollToPosition(0);


}

public static class orderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View view;
    RelativeLayout orderCard;
    public orderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view =itemView;
        orderCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderCard);


    }
    public void setName(String Name){
        TextView rollTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rollTextView);
        rollTextView.setText(Name);
    }
    public void setPrice(String Price){
        TextView mobileTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobileTextView);
        mobileTextView.setText(Price);
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId){
        TextView orderidTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.orderidTextView);
        orderidTextView.setText(userId);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your onStart have the implementation to initialize the Recycler, Adapter and: Collection DATA!

So if your Fragment lose the visibility, when another Activity is in full screen, and you come back to your Fragment hided, you execute a request, obtains data, and set to Recycler, but, this is a new Collection so the Recycler put in first position.

You need to save your Collection in onSaveInstanceState and restore it in onActivityCreated() and set it to the Adapter.

With this approach your must change a lot of Fragment implementation because you are not contemplate the Lifecycle!

Comment: can you clarify more about this such as how to implement these function and how to use,as i am beginner in android studio